# windows phone 8 - activating the app from the background agent

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-8, background-agent

I have a WP8 app in which i want to be able to create and schedule an alarm from the background agent. But the API ScheduledActionService.Add() cannot be called from the background agent.

So, i thought of a work-around where if the background agent can activate the app, then the app, while running in the foreground, will schedule the alarm.

Is there a way we can activate the app from the background agent?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way we can activate the app from the background agent?

No.
Launching an app requires user interaction, there is no way to do this programmatically.